# Scrape URLs with Beautiful Soup and Append to lists

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm having trouble appending scraped data to the lists.
The lists display only one url scraped data. I need all of the data in those two lists.
Please help.

Here's the sample of my work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/2019',
        'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-volleyball/roster',
        'https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    height_volley = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-height") 
    first_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-first-name")
    last_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-last-name")
    print(height_volley)
    print(first_name_data)
    print(last_name_data)

    first_name = []
    last_name = []
    for text in first_name_data:
      name = text.get_text()
      first_name.append(name)
    for text in last_name_data:
     name = text.get_text()
     last_name.append(name)
    print(first_name)
    print(last_name)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['First Name'] = first_name
    df['Last Name'] = last_name
    df
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function to scrape each link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_roster(url):
   d = soup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
   return [{'name':i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-name h3 a').text,
            'number':i.select_one('span.sidearm-roster-player-jersey-number').get_text(strip=True),
            'position':getattr(i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-position-long-short'), 'get_text', lambda **_:None)(strip=True),
            'height':i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-height').get_text(strip=True),
            'year':i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-academic-year').get_text(strip=True),
            'hometown':i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-hometown').get_text(strip=True),
            'highschool':getattr(i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-highschool'), 'text', None)}
             for i in d.select('ul.sidearm-roster-players li.sidearm-roster-player')]
   

urls = ['https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/2019',
    'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-volleyball/roster',
    'https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster']
result = list(map(get_roster, urls))
```

Output:

```
[[{'name': 'Snigdho Hasan', 'number': '2', 'position': 'Libero', 'height': '5\'5"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, NY', 'highschool': 'Midwood'}, {'name': 'Michael  Valentin', 'number': '3', 'position': 'Setter', 'height': '5\'9"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, NY', 'highschool': 'LaGuardia'}, {'name': 'Andres Vargas', 'number': '4', 'position': 'Outside Hitter', 'height': '6\'0"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Bogota, Colombia', 'highschool': 'Lawrence Senior'}, {'name': 'Jasper Diangco', 'number': '7', 'position': 'Outside Hitter', 'height': '5\'10"', 'year': 'So.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, NY', 'highschool': 'James Madison'}, {'name': 'Sayuj Zachariah', 'number': '9', 'position': 'Setter', 'height': '6\'2"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Floral Park, NY', 'highschool': 'St. Francis Prep'}, {'name': 'Omar  Rezika', 'number': '13', 'position': 'Middle Hitter', 'height': '6\'2"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, NY', 'highschool': 'Rachel Carson'}, {'name': 'Gabriel Pjatak', 'number': '14', 'position': 'Middle Blocker', 'height': '6\'3"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Maly Lipnik, Slovakia', 'highschool': 'James Madison'}, {'name': 'Ryan  Chabel', 'number': '16', 'position': 'Outside Hitter', 'height': '5\'11"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, NY', 'highschool': None}, {'name': 'Utku  Tanritanir', 'number': '17', 'position': 'Defensive Specialist', 'height': '6\'0"', 'year': 'So.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, NY', 'highschool': 'Abraham Lincoln'}], [{'name': 'QiQin Zeng', 'number': '1', 'position': 'Outside Hitter', 'height': '5\'9"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Guangdong, China', 'highschool': 'Emma Lazarus (NY)'}, {'name': 'Andrew Tsororos', 'number': '2', 'position': 'Right Side', 'height': '6\'4"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Hauppauge, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Hauppauge'}, {'name': 'Steven Lopez', 'number': '3', 'position': 'Outside Hitter', 'height': '6\'0"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Port Washington, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Paul D. Schreiber'}, {'name': 'Sonam Dorjee', 'number': '4', 'position': 'Outside Hitter', 'height': '5\'10"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Woodside, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Academy of American Studies'}, {'name': 'Edward Grinberg', 'number': '5', 'position': 'Setter', 'height': '6\'2"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'M.S.I.T'}, {'name': 'David Sirchenko', 'number': '6', 'position': 'Middle Hitter', 'height': '6\'3"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Staten Island, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Staten Island Tech'}, {'name': 'Stallone Shankar', 'number': '7', 'position': 'Setter', 'height': '6\'0"', 'year': 'So.', 'hometown': 'Jackson Heights, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Aviation'}, {'name': 'Rabsang Andrugtsang', 'number': '9', 'position': 'Libero/Defensive Specialist', 'height': '5\'10"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Rego Park, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Forest Hills'}, {'name': 'Hanbin Lee', 'number': '10', 'position': 'Libero', 'height': '5\'9"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Briarwood, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Forest Hills'}, {'name': 'Artem Zinkin', 'number': '11', 'position': 'Right Side', 'height': '6\'5"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Midwood'}, {'name': 'Michael Higgins', 'number': '12', 'position': 'Middle Hitter', 'height': '6\'4"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Valley Stream, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Valley Stream Central'}, {'name': 'Carlos Rodriguez', 'number': '13', 'position': 'Outside Hitter/Right Side', 'height': '6\'4"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Bronx, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Walton Campus'}, {'name': 'Leon Petrovitsky', 'number': '14', 'position': 'Right Side', 'height': '6\'5"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'James Madison'}, {'name': 'Defeng Han', 'number': '15', 'position': 'Outside Hitter/Right Side', 'height': '6\'1"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Fort Hamilton'}, {'name': 'Evan Takos', 'number': '16', 'position': 'Middle Hitter', 'height': '6\'3"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Bayside, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Saint Francis Prep'}, {'name': 'Meni Musheyev', 'number': '17', 'position': 'Middle Hitter', 'height': '6\'3"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Forest Hills, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Metro Campus'}, {'name': 'Justin Iloulian', 'number': '18', 'position': 'Outside Hitter/Right Side', 'height': '6\'2"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Plainview, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Plainview-Old Bethpage JFK'}], [{'name': 'John Vitor', 'number': '2', 'position': 'DS/L', 'height': '5\'6"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Manila, Philippines', 'highschool': 'Martin Van Buren'}, {'name': 'Juan Rodriguez', 'number': '3', 'position': 'L/S', 'height': '5\'6"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Santiago, Dominican Republic', 'highschool': 'Academy for Language and Technology'}, {'name': 'Shawn Nemoto', 'number': '4', 'position': 'L', 'height': '5\'7"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Floral Park, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Thomas Edison CTE'}, {'name': 'Erick Ortega', 'number': '5', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '5\'8"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Queens, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Benjamin Franklin HS for Finance & Information Technology'}, {'name': 'Akil Vaughn', 'number': '6', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '6\'5"', 'year': 'Jr.', 'hometown': 'Georgetown, Guyana', 'highschool': 'St. Roses'}, {'name': 'Justin Saji', 'number': '7', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '5\'10"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Kerala, India', 'highschool': 'Sewanhaka'}, {'name': 'Jayden Deokinanan', 'number': '8', 'position': None, 'height': '5\'4"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'John Adams'}, {'name': 'Mambe Koureissi', 'number': '9', 'position': 'MB', 'height': '6\'4"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Harlem, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Environmental Studies'}, {'name': 'Anthony Nazario, Jr.', 'number': '10', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '5\'9"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Bronx, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'DeWitt Clinton'}, {'name': 'Olawale Kila', 'number': '12', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '6\'4"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Nigeria', 'highschool': 'Broome Street Academy Charter'}, {'name': 'David Heyliger, Jr.', 'number': '13', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '6\'1"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'St. Thomas, U.S. Virgin Islands', 'highschool': 'Charlotte Amalie'}, {'name': 'Guillermo Hernandez', 'number': '14', 'position': 'MH', 'height': '6\'4"', 'year': 'So.', 'hometown': 'New York, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Gregorio Luperon'}, {'name': 'Fatmir Glavatovic', 'number': '15', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '6\'0"', 'year': 'Sr.', 'hometown': 'Brooklyn, N.Y.', 'highschool': 'Secondary School for Law'}, {'name': ' Ti’Juan Boothe', 'number': '16', 'position': 'OH', 'height': '5\'8"', 'year': 'Fr.', 'hometown': 'Kingston, Jamaica', 'highschool': 'Excelsior Prep'}]]
```

Comment: It's a very nice way of handing AttributeError or similar stuff. I've one question on this: how would you parse href when you use `getattr()` on this `soup.select_one("a").get("href")`? I tried like `getattr(soup.select_one("a"),"href",None)` but failed. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU Since `select_one` will either return `None` or a `bs4` object, I would use an assignment expression with an inline conditional: `None if (a:=soup.select_one("a")) is None else a.get('href')`. You would use `getattr` if `soup`  itself could be `None`: `getattr(soup, 'select_one', lambda _:{})().get('href')`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you debug your code step by step to resolve this kind of issues.

The dataframe you declared is reset in each iteration.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/2019',
        'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-volleyball/roster',
        'https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster']

df_list = list()

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    height_volley = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-height") 
    first_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-first-name")
    last_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-last-name")

    first_name = []
    last_name = []

    for text in first_name_data:
        name = text.get_text()
        first_name.append(name)
    for text in last_name_data:
        name = text.get_text()
        last_name.append(name)

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
    df_temp['First Name'] = first_name
    df_temp['Last Name'] = last_name

    df_list.append(df_temp)

df_result = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(df_result)
```

EDIT (based on Ajax1234's response) to answer the later question.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/2019',
    'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-volleyball/roster',
    'https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster'
]
 
def get_roster(url):
    d = soup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    return pd.DataFrame([
        {
            'name': i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-name h3 a').get_text(strip=True),
            'height': i.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-height').get_text(strip=True),
        }
        for i in d.select('ul.sidearm-roster-players li.sidearm-roster-player')
    ])
   
df_result = pd.concat(map(get_roster, urls), ignore_index=True)
df_result[['first_name','last_name']] = df_result['name'].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)

del df_result['name']
print(df_result)
```

Comment: Hi Ismail, Thanks for help. I have another question about the scraped height, when I try append it to the df, it gives me ValueError: Length of values (18) does not match length of index (11), any suggestions? Here's what I did for height:                                                    for text in height_volley:
        feet, inches = text.get_text()[:-1].split("'")
        height.append(int(feet) * 12 + int(inches))

Comment: My pleasure. 
Please make a new question next time or add it in the same question above.
I've edited my response, now it contains more code for your question.
I hope this helps.

You can refer to @Ajax1234 for more details if you need to parse more data such as the player's position etc.

Answer (score 0):

'Cause you reset your dataframe at each iteration :

Note : It is a good practice to add **headers** to your request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.brooklyncollegeathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster/2019',
        'https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-volleyball/roster',
        'https://yorkathletics.com/sports/mens-volleyball/roster']

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"}

df = pd.DataFrame()
first_name = []
last_name = []
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    height_volley = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-height") 
    first_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-first-name")
    last_name_data = soup.findAll('span', class_ = "sidearm-roster-player-last-name")
    print(height_volley)
    print(first_name_data)
    print(last_name_data)

    
    for text in first_name_data:
        name = text.get_text()
        first_name.append(name)
    for text in last_name_data:
        name = text.get_text()
        last_name.append(name)
    print(first_name)
    print(last_name)
    
df['First Name'] = first_name
df['Last Name'] = last_name
df
```